# Good OPDS Server for Shared Hosting?

Tags: open-source

Does anyone have recommendations for a web-based server I can use to host an [OPDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPDS) server that does not require something heavy like a VPS?  I realized the FBReader and other mobile e-book readers would allow me to syndicate myself between me and friends.  Google has few answers in this regard, beyond [the formal specification website by Google](http://code.google.com/p/openpub/wiki/OPDS).

Comment: This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 2):

After doing the same search I found the following candidates :

- Calibre2OPDS : http://calibre2opds.com/ (generate static files from a Calibre database)
- Parthagar : http://olpcsf.org/projects/pathagar-sheevaplug-edition (in python)
- COPS : http://blog.slucas.fr/en/oss/calibre-opds-php-server (PHP server using a Calibre database)

So not a full answer, but close enough ;)

Comment: there's also [Ubooquity](http://vaemendis.net/ubooquity) which is still actively developed and looks quite promising (Java)